# Error calling forEach on array

Tags: javascript, node.js, foreach

I am getting a problem forEach within anoter forEach function:

The `results` variable contains an object like:

```
{
    names: [
        'Someone',
        'Someone else'
    ],
    emails: [
        'someone@someemail.com'
        'something@somemail.com'
    ]
}
```

I want it to unwind all the arrays and result in an array like this:

```
[
    {term: 'Someone', type: 'names'},
    ...
]
```

Here is my code:

```
var keys = _.keys(results);

console.log(keys);

var finalResult = [];

keys.forEach( function (key) {

    var arrTerms = results[key];

    console.log(key, arrTerms); //arrTerms prints fine

    arrTerms.forEach(function (term) { //This line throws an exception

        finalResult.push({
            term: term,
            type: key
        });
    });

});
```

The nested call to forEach throws the following exception:

```
TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot call method 'forEach' of undefined
```

I tried using a for loop with iteration till length, but it generated another exception:

```
TypeError: Uncaught error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Comment: Try, `console.log(key, arrTerms, Array.isArray(arrTerms));`

Comment: The code as it is works fine for me (except your missing a comma in your array definition).  What does `results` actually look like?

Comment: It prints typeOf as Object

Comment: @ZeMoon Sorry, try `Array.isArray`. I edited the comment

Comment: @thefourtheye `Array.isArray(arrTerms)` returns `true`

Comment: @ExplosionPills I have posted the structure of results in the beginning of the question

Comment: You might have something that extends `Object.prototype`. What's the value of `keys`? (also, if `arrTerms` is `undefined`, `Array.isArray` cannot return `true`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you may  assign undefined to your arrTerms (when results[key] returns undefined cause you take a key which isn't contained in your object). Try to do this:

```
var keys = _.keys(results);

console.log(keys);

var finalResult = [];

keys.forEach( function (key) {
    if(results[key] != undefined){
     var arrTerms = results[key];

     arrTerms.forEach(function (term) { //This line throws an exception
        console.log(key, arrTerms); //arrTerms prints fine
        finalResult.push({
            term: term,
            type: key
        });
     });
    }
});
```

Comment: So, what happens to `attTerms` if  `results[key]` is `undefined`?

Comment: Just nothing. :) We don't want to do anything if we can't find the key, do we?

Comment: But you are still calling `arrTerms.forEach` even if `results[key]` is undefined.

Comment: Oh, overseen that :) ty

Comment: This worked! The problem arose because there were other keys in the Object which were undefined. I just put the second `forEach`  under `if (arrTerms)`. Undefined keys do not show up using NSLog, but still exist for Underscore.Keys() to find!

Comment: I've edited that :) Overseen on the first try :$ Felix pointed this out already

Comment: @ZeMoon: `_.keys`, just like `Object.keys`, will get all property names of the object. So if you have `{foo: undefined}`, then you get `['foo']`. So it seems, after all, you didn't post the actual structure of the object :P I wonder why didn't catch that, since you called `console.log(keys);` already.

Comment: Yeah well. I got stuck. It seems like the whole thing was based on just a silly mistake.